# Acronym package: printonlyreused and capitalizing doesn't work

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

The recent version of the `acronym` package provides options to only print multiply used acronyms (`[printonlyreused]`) to the list of acronyms as well as capitalizing e.g. long versions (`\Acl{XYZ}`).
Capitalizing worked for me in an earlier version.
I updated the package to version 1.46 but none of the above mentioned works now.
I also re-installed the required packages `suffix` and `xstring`.
I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.7380 with PDFlatex and also reset MiKTeX configuration but nothing helped.

Please find below a MWE to describe the problem. In my output, the long version of A is not capitalized, and B is still on the list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[printonlyreused]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section{Chapter}
First use: \ac{NA}  \\
2nd use: \ac{NA}   \\
Long version with capital: \Acl{NA} \\
Other acronym, only mentioned once: \ac{NB} \\
The third acro is not mentioned to be excluded on the printed list

\section{List of acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{NA}{new acro A}
\acro{NB}{new acro B} % negative test for [printonlyreused]
\acro{NC}{new acro C} % negative test for [printonlyused]
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

As a workaround I switched to package `acro`, luckily it uses mostly the same in-text commands so I didn't have to change much in my 130 pages document, only redefining >4 pages of acronyms was somewhat tedious. However, a solution using `acronym` would still be useful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour described in the question. Given that this sounds like a bug, did you contact the package author? https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/issues

Comment: For the capitalisation I have my eyes on https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/commit/c14ea865ed50ffcfea5ebd0de7a0efcf00af09c5.

Comment: Thanks for testing, I thought then I might have messed up something in my MikTeX, but now it seems to be something general. I wrote an Email to the developer.

Comment: https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/issues/25